# Google Maps API drawing custom markers : Need help understanding this example I found

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, polygon

I found this example of a google map custom marker that draws a pin shape.

```
function setMarker(map, lat, lng, name) {
    var position = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: position,
        icon: pinSymbol('red'),
    });

    marker.setMap(map);
}

function pinSymbol(color) {
    return {
        path: 'M 0,0 C -2,-20 -10,-22 -10,-30 A 10,10 0 1,1 10,-30 C 10,-22 2,-20 0,0 z',
        fillColor: color,
        fillOpacity: 0.5,
        strokeColor: '#000',
        strokeWeight: 1,
        scale: 1.5
    };
}
```

I need help understanding this part:

```
path: 'M 0,0 C -2,-20 -10,-22 -10,-30 A 10,10 0 1,1 10,-30 C 10,-22 2,-20 0,0 z',
```

How does this draw a pin shape? I've been trying for a while to figure out this format of drawing with no luck. How would I draw a rectangle or another polygon instead of a pin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pin shape is determined using [SVG PathData](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathData). The "path" attribute describes the shape using several instructions and coordinates.

> A path is defined by including a ‘path’ element which contains a d="(path data)" attribute, where the ‘d’ attribute contains the moveto, line, curve (both cubic and quadratic Béziers), arc and closepath instructions.

Basically each letter is an instruction and each number is a coordinate. 
"M x y" executes the command "MOVETO" and moves the cursor the point of coordinate (x,y). The list of commands is available on the link above.

You could manually construct your shape, however it would get cumbersome for more complex icons. You can get the PathData from more complex SVG files using Gimp or Inkscape.

Comment: What if I wanted to draw a SVG circle instead of a pin? What would I change in the code?